# Casting Int to Float in z3

Tags: z3, z3py

How do you cast an `Int` to any type of `Float` in z3 or z3py? For example:

```py
from z3 import *
    
s = Solver()
foo = Int('foo')
bar = FP('bar', Float32())
baz = FP('baz', Float32())
s.add( foo == 5 )
s.add( bar == 5.0 )
s.add( baz == bar * foo )
```

Gives the error `z3.z3types.Z3Exception: sort mismatch` when it encounters `bar * foo`.

Also, I'm aware that `Float`s do not have the infinite precision of `Real`s. In my case an approximate solution is fine and `Real`s are too slow.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct conversion from `Int` to `Float`. You first have to go through `Real`. (See https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml for details.)

So, your last line should read:

```py
s.add(baz == bar * fpRealToFP(RNE(), ToReal(foo), Float32()))
```

Note that you have to specify a rounding mode. I used `RNE` above (round-nearest-ties-to-even), but there are other modes available too. See the `Rounding modes` section of the document I linked above.